# Dynamic-data SourceList new added items does not refresh when selected/deselected

Tags: c#, reactiveui, dynamic-data

I have a SourceList and a ReadOnlyObservableCollection.

```
    public SourceList<T> SourceList { get; set; } = new SourceList<T>();
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> ActiveList;
```

And bind applies with below code:

```
   SourceList.Connect()
      .Filter(criteria, ListFilterPolicy.ClearAndReplace)
      .Transform((item, i) => { item.DisplayOrder = i + 1; return item; })
      .Bind(out ActiveList)
      .Subscribe();
```

And the list displays in a window :

```
   listItemsControl.ItemsSource = ViewModel.ActiveList;
```

And I bind IsSelected of any item to IsChecked of a ToggleButton.
Everything is good until I add new item to the SourceList.
For new added items, the binding is not work.

Thanks for any idea to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the `criteria` that you're filtering the `SourceList` on is checking against `IsSelected`, then you'll likely have to add an [AutoRefresh](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/dynamicdata/observablecacheex/678dfcc9):

```
   SourceList.Connect()
     .AutoRefresh(x=> x.IsSelected)
     .Filter(criteria, ListFilterPolicy.ClearAndReplace)
     .Transform((item, i) => { item.DisplayOrder = i + 1; return item; })
     .Bind(out ActiveList)
     .Subscribe();
```

By default, a `SourceList` will only push collection changes down the pipeline and won't account for property changes within any given item. By adding `AutoRefresh`, changes to that property within the source will cause its parent be sent down the pipeline.